# How can I paralelize two for statements equally between threads using OpenMP?

Tags: c, openmp

Lets say I have the following code:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for  (i = 0; i < array.size; i++ ) {
   int temp = array[i];
   for (p = 0; p < array2.size; p++) {
      array2[p] = array2[p] + temp;
```

How can I divide the `array2.size` between the threads that I call when I do the `#pragma omp parallel for` in the first line? For what I understood when I do the `#pragma omp parallel for` I'll spawn several threads in such a way that each thread will have a part of the `array.size` so that the `i` will never be the same between threads. But in this case I also want those same threads to have a different part of the `array2.size` (their `p` will also never be the same between them) so that I dont have all the threads doing the same calculation in the second for.

I've tried the `collapse` notation but it seems that this is only used for perfect for statements since I couldn't get the result I wanted.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance

Comment: You can spawn other threads in thread, so why not adding a second `#pragma omp parallel for` before the `for (p=0...` ?

Comment: But wouldnt that  make it spawn several threads for each thread that I spawned in the previous for? If I initially spawn 5 threads and do another `#pragma omp parallel for` before the last for, wouldnt I have 5 threads spawn several other threads each, hence making the concurrency problem arise nevertheless? Thanks for the reply!

Comment: It won't by default.  This is called nesting and unless explicitly enabled the p loop would run sequentially when a `parallel for` would be added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that multiple threads will try to modify `array2` at the same time (race condition). This can easily be avoided by reordering the loops. If `array2.size` doesn't provide enough parallelism, you may apply the `collapse` clause, as the loops are now in canonical form.

```cpp
#pragma omp parallel for
for (p = 0; p < array2.size; p++) {
    for (i = 0; i < array.size; i++ ) {
        array2[p] += array[i];
    }
}
```

You shouldn't expect too much of this though as the ratio between loads/stores and computation is very bad. This is without a doubt memory-bound and not compute-bound.

EDIT: If this is really your problem and not just a minimal example, I would also try the following:

```cpp
#pragma omp parallel 
{
    double sum = 0.;
    #pragma omp for reduction(+: sum)
    for (i = 0; i < array.size; i++) {
        sum += array[i];
    }
    #pragma omp for
    for (p = 0; p < array2.size; p++) {
        array2[p] += sum;
    }
}
```